# How to externally interact with python TCP protocol

Tags: python, python-asyncio, network-protocols

I have an echo client based on the python documentation as follow:

```
import asyncio

class EchoClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, message, on_con_lost):
        self.message = message
        self.on_con_lost = on_con_lost
        self.loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        transport.write(self.message.encode())
        print('Data sent: {!r}'.format(self.message))

    def write_to_device(self):
        self.transport.write(self.message.encode())
    
    def data_received(self, data):
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(data.decode()))
        self.loop.call_later(1.0 , self.write_to_device)

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('The server closed the connection')
        self.on_con_lost.set_result(True)


async def main(): 
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    on_con_lost = loop.create_future()
    message = 'Hello World!'

    transport, protocol = await loop.create_connection(
        lambda: EchoClientProtocol(message, on_con_lost),
        '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    try:
        await on_con_lost
    finally:
        transport.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Everytime it receives a message from server, it sends again the message after 1 second. My question is: How can I change the message to send once the connection is made?

Comment: Transports and protocols are a low-level tool whose use is not recommended except in very specialized circumstances. Have you considered using [streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html) instead?

Comment: yes, I have also an implementation with streams. Just wanted to run on uvloop and check for improvements, just with a callback-based protocol.

Comment: This question doesn't contain a runnable example that reproduces the issue and doesn't state what the issue is, just that it "doesn't work".

Comment: Oki, I will reformulate the question

Comment: The question is still unclear. How is the separate task created? Why can't it receive the protocol instance and, when needed, just modify `p.cmdi`? Again, the code in the answer is insufficient to understand the context.

Comment: Well, Why can't it receive the protocol instance and when needed just modify p.cmdi.... this is exactly what I want to do: "modify the protocol while the connection is being serviced".

Comment: So, where exactly is the problem - which part do you not know how to do? Create a task? Pass the protocol instance to the task you've created? Assign a different value to `p.cmdi` from a task? I genuinely don't understand where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Oki, just simply modifying the protocol instance as suggested works... here is a simple proof:

```
import asyncio


class EchoClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, message, on_con_lost):
        self.message = message
        self.on_con_lost = on_con_lost
        self.loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        transport.write(self.message.encode())
        print('Data sent: {!r}'.format(self.message))

    def write_to_device(self):
        print('Data sent: {!r}'.format(self.message))
        self.transport.write(self.message.encode())

    def data_received(self, data):
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(data.decode()))
        self.loop.call_later(1, self.write_to_device)


    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('The server closed the connection')
        self.on_con_lost.set_result(True)


async def changeMessage(message, protocol):
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('Changing message')
    protocol.message = message


async def main():
    # Get a reference to the event loop as we plan to use
    # low-level APIs.
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    on_con_lost = loop.create_future()
    message = 'Hello World!'

    transport, protocol = await loop.create_connection(
        lambda: EchoClientProtocol(message, on_con_lost),
        '127.0.0.1', 65432)

    await changeMessage('Message is now changed', protocol)

    # Wait until the protocol signals that the connection
    # is lost and close the transport.
    try:
        await on_con_lost
    finally:
        transport.close()


asyncio.run(main())
```